# Zsh peco-history issue after updating to Ubuntu 23.10 - Weird signs in prompt after pressing Ctrl+R

Tags: command-line, zsh, 23.10

I recently updated my Ubuntu distribution to version 23.10, and I've been experiencing an issue with zsh and peco-history. Prior to the update, everything was working fine, but now I'm encountering a problem when I try to use reverse search (Ctrl+R) in my terminal.

After pressing Ctrl+R to initiate the search, instead of getting the expected behavior, my prompt displays strange characters or symbols, making it impossible to find and execute previous commands efficiently.

I suspect this could be related to changes in the new Ubuntu release or some compatibility issues, but I'm not entirely sure.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with zsh and peco-history after updating to Ubuntu 23.10, and if so, do you have any insights or solutions to resolve this problem? I've tried various troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause or find a fix.

Here's some additional information:

I'm using zsh as my shell with oh-my-zsh.
peco-history is a handy plugin that I use regularly for command history search.
I've updated all my packages and plugins, and my zsh configuration seems to be intact.
The issue appears only after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.
Any help or guidance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was unrelated to zsh and was specifically related to the version of peco.
The issue was resolved by using an older version of peco, specifically "peco version v0.5.3 (built with go1.10.4)."